# How to access option label

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
<select id="j_idt14:companyidCompany"  
        name="j_idt14:companyidCompany" size="1"     
        title="CompanyidCompany" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','j_idt14:companyidCompany',
               'j_idt14:locationnCollection')"> 
   <option value="">---</option>
   <option value="1">Nike</option>
   <option value="2">Adidas</option>
   <option value="3">Puma</option>
</select>
```

And I need the name of my Company.

```
var companyName = document.getElementById('j_idt14:companyidCompany').value;
```

This returns the position in the Array of the select element but not the name. How can I get the company name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var select = document.getElementById('j_idt14:companyidCompany');

var company = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
```

---

Though it seems like the first argument passed is the element, which means it could be shortened if you use the parameter that receives the argument.

If it's called `el`, then you'd do:

```
var company = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, squint's solution will work. But this is a very dangerous idea, as you **can never rely on the ids autogenerated by JSF implementations**.

What **has to be done is to assign an id to the enclosing `<h:form>`**, that is a naming container, like in

```
<h:form id="form">
```

In this case your `<h:selectOneMenu>` will have client id `form:companyidCompany` that you can **always** rely on when doing JavaScript manipulations.

Another alternative is to use `prependId="false"` on the form so that clients ids of form children won't be changed:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

In this case your `<h:selectOneMenu>` will have client id exactly `companyidCompany`.

Comment: OP basically asked how to get the option label in JS, this has further nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: @BalusC That's why I referred to the accepted answer as the right one. The reason behind answering was to warn OP of `document.getElementById('j_idt14:companyidCompany')` part, which in my opinion is very dangerous.

Comment: I know, but this is not an answer. The post is just more suitable as a comment if the post does not contain the answer.